# How to use knockoutjs click binding to create a hamburger menu

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

My current repo https://github.com/matosb2/P5

I'd like to be able to refactor this particular code using knockoutjs instead of jQuery.  How would I go about doing this?

```
var menu = document.querySelector('#burgMenu');
var main = document.querySelector('main');
var drawer = document.querySelector('#drawer');

menu.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    drawer.classList.toggle('open');
    e.stopPropagation();
});
main.addEventListener('click', function() {
    drawer.classList.remove('open');
});
```

I know there are errors with the functionality of other parts of my project but for now I just want to focus on this.  Feel free to look at my repo for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the three DOM elements. Two of them will have click bindings and one will have a css binding. You have one variable that represents whether the drawer is open, used in the CSS binding. The click bindings control its value. As far as Knockout is concerned, it's just this:

```js
vm = {
  isOpen: ko.observable(false),
  toggle: function() {
    vm.isOpen(!vm.isOpen());
  },
  close: function() {
    vm.isOpen(false);
  }
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```css
.open {
  height: 20rem;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="click: toggle">Burger Menu</div>
<div data-bind="click: close">Main</div>
<div data-bind="css: {open: isOpen}">Drawer</div>
```

If you have not been through the [Knockout tutorial](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/), I highly recommend it.